# What it "village halfwit"?

Tags: meaning

I tried to understand "village halfwit", but was not able to know the exact meaning.
I think it seems to be some people cannot work or something.
Could you explain the meaning for me?

Comment: Hi jokim, our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "please, don’t ask any questions about ... *(t)he meaning of words, or synonyms for words, unless you have first looked them up in a dictionary or thesaurus*." For further guidance, see [ask], and I also recommend taking the **[Tour]** of our site :-)

Comment: I had looked into dictionaries and some websites, but did not get it exactly and thought it must have a special meaning, then I posted this. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

'Wit' essentially means 'intelligence', and as such can be found in common expressions like 'you need to keep your wits about you'.

'Halfwit' is therefore someone with low intelligence.

'Village' - with small populations a certain amount of inbreeding can take place, not infrequently producing 'halfwits' if the social record is to be believed.

> Village halfwit - someone who acts in a stupid manner

Answer (score 1):

The common term is ***village idiot***:

> someone who is well known in their community for their stupidity and ignorant behaviour
>   *[Colins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/village-idiot)*
>
> The village idiot in strict terms is a person locally known for
>   ignorance or stupidity, but is also a common term for a
>   stereotypically silly or nonsensical person or stock character. The
>   term is also used as a stereotype of the mentally disabled. It has
>   also been applied as an epithet for an unrealistically optimistic or
>   naive individual.
>
> The village idiot was long considered an acceptable social role, a
>   unique individual who was dependent yet contributed to the social
>   fabric of his community.
>   *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Village_idiot)*

*Halfwit* is simply a synonym for *idiot*.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been fairly well answered in terms of a definition, but I feel it could be explained better as to its usage, both past and present.

The more common term is "*Village Idiot*". Your example is just a variation, or perhaps a softer term than "idiot".

In the early 20th century, the term "idiot" was actually officially used in psychiatry and was not just a pejorative term. It was one of a number of designations that denoted an IQ range:

> IQ of 0–25 = Idiot
>   IQ of 26-50 = Imbecile
>   IQ of 51-70 = Moron

All of the above have long since ceased to be used by professionals and nowadays are all considered to be *pejorative terms* that imply someone has low intelligence.

The term "village idiot" stems back to that same era of psychiatry in the UK. It would be applied to people with lower intelligence or a condition which today would be understood and dealt with much more sensitively. The term was a "label" that would be given to someone in a neighbourhood or village known or thought to be an "idiot". Villages in the UK were, and in some cases still are, the smallest communities where everybody is more likely to know one another's business, and that is why such a term was more likely to originate from them.

"Village idiot" today is used in a number of different ways, all pejorative. It normally implies that a person is stupid, and known to be so within a certain community. For example, if someone was described as "the village idiot" at work, it may imply that everybody at the place of work knows them as such.

"Half-wit" as used in your example has never been a psychiatry term and is always pejorative. It literally means that a person has "half" the wit, or intelligence of a normal person.

For an example of how the term "village idiot" has been used in humour, look no further than [this Monty Python sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF-CkMpQtlY) from 1970.

Answer (score 0):

While I largely agree with Trevor's explanation, the stupidity concept has nothing with to do with inbreeding villagers. Normally, villagers are assumed to be simple folk. So, when you say 'village half-wit' it likely refers to a half-wit who happens to be a villager.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. The "village half-wit" or "village idiot" is someone whose sole purpose is to sit around saying and doing dimwitted things. In a village full of people who are identified mainly by their jobs, there's... Jerry.